# How to sort this list of strings using a substring?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list whose elements are like the following:

```
Region_1.csv, Region_33.csv, Region_2.csv, Region_4.csv, Region_105.csv, ....
```

The list has all numbers ranging from 1-105 with none missing.
I want to sort this list according to the region number such that it looks like this:

```
Region_1.csv, Region_2.csv, Region_3.csv, Region_4.csv, Region_105.csv etc.
```

Since the numbers have variable digits, I am struggling to sort this list.

Thanks.

Comment: and what you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a custom function, splitting first by `.` and then by `_`:

```
res = sorted(L, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]))

print(res)

['Region_1.csv', 'Region_2.csv', 'Region_4.csv', 'Region_33.csv', 'Region_105.csv']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]))
print(lst)

# ['Region_1.csv', 'Region_2.csv', 'Region_4.csv', 'Region_33.csv', 'Region_105.csv']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `re` module, if you want to find in string something fancy:

```
l = ['Region_105.csv', 'Region_1.csv', 'Region_33.csv', 'Region_2.csv', 'Region_4.csv']

import re
print(sorted(l, key=lambda v: int(re.findall('\d+', v)[0])))
```

Output:

> ['Region_1.csv', 'Region_2.csv', 'Region_4.csv', 'Region_33.csv',
>   'Region_105.csv']

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `find` method of strings:

```
inList = ['Region_1.csv', 'Region_33.csv', 'Region_2.csv', 'Region_4.csv', 'Region_105.csv']

outList = sorted(inList, key=lambda elem: int(elem[elem.find('_')+1:elem.find('.')]))

print(outList)
```

Output:

```
['Region_1.csv', 'Region_2.csv', 'Region_4.csv', 'Region_33.csv', 'Region_105.csv']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
>>> l = ['Region_105.csv', 'Region_1.csv', 'Region_33.csv', 'Region_2.csv', 'Region_4.csv']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x))))
['Region_1.csv', 'Region_2.csv', 'Region_4.csv', 'Region_33.csv', 'Region_105.csv']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the region number using regular expressions and create a dictionary of the form {region number: fileName} and then sort the dictionary based on the keys.
Code for extracting region number and create dictionary:

```
import re
files=['Region_1.csv','Region_33.csv','Region_2.csv','Region_4.csv','Region_105.csv']
d=dict()
for f in files:
   rnum=re.find('[a-bA-B]_([0-9])\.csv$',f)
   d[rnum]=f
```

For sorting the items in dictionary, refer : [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)