# I have a problem with import and loading image data respectively in python

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm beginner in python.my problem happens when i want to import some image from a folder with names.

my files:
building_3.tif
building_21.tif
building_22.tif
building_25.tif
building_27.tif
building_36.tif
building_44.tif
building_49.tif
building_53.tif
building_70.tif
building_101.tif
building_248.tif
building_1002.tif

i just want to import them and placed in a nd matrix(tensor) respectively.
for example if we have (14,264,120) tensor , building_1002 should be placed in last (13,264,120) and building_3 placed in first(0,264,120).

### no error happens but the building images is not placed respectively in tensor.

```
import numpy as np 
import glob
import os
from PIL import Image

path = '/path/'


image_list = []
all_data =np.zeros((14,264,120))
i=0
for filename in glob.glob(path + '/building_*.tif'): 
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
    n = len(image_list)
    all_data[i,:,:]=im
    i=i+1
```

[variable explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Nle.png)

the respectively that happens is :
building_1002.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_101.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_21.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_22.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_23.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_248.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_25.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_27.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_3.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_36.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_44.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_49.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_53.tif (264, 120, 4)
building_70.tif (264, 120, 4)

Thanks in advance for your cooperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.
from venkata krishnan
and from this link [How to sort this list of strings using a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301769/how-to-sort-this-list-of-strings-using-a-substring)

the correct answer is :

```
names = glob.glob('building_*.tif')
list_names= sorted(names, key=lambda elem:int(elem[elem.find('_')+1:elem.find('.')]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the filenames beforehand

```
names = glob.glob(path + '/building_*.tif')
names = sorted(names,lambda x:x.split(".")[0].split("_")[1])
```

then use the names array to read the files in the for loop.

Comment: if you find this answer useful, please mark this as accepted answer, which will help the future users.

Comment: thank you venkata krishnan. I'm using your answers and others to find out my problem.names = glob.glob('building_*.tif')
list_names= sorted(names, key=lambda elem: int(elem[elem.find('_')+1:elem.find('.')]))

Comment: i just missed converting it to int. you did it. thanks for accepting the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seem you only assign (14,264,120) that much space for 14*(264, 120, 4). Maybe you should assign (264,120,4*14) for enough space for the pictures.